# What should come first in HTML, an anchor or a header?

Tags: html, semantics

I'm wondering which of the following two orders is semantically correct in HTML:

```
1. <h1><a>Header</a></h1>
2. <a><h1>Header</h1></a>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<h1><a>Header</a></h1>
```

`<h1>` is a block-level element and `<a>` is not, it is syntactically invalid HTML to have block level elements inside inline elements (at least until HTML5) which is how the other way would be.

Comment: Anyone reading this at the time I comment should know that either is acceptable in HTML5. Source: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/anchor-tag-inside-h1-or-h1-inside-achor-tag-which-is-better

Answer (score 9):

This answer on a duplicate question is better than mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023551/20578

But, for posterity:

---

Semantically, there’s no difference. Remember, “semantic” just means “related to meaning”, and meaning is just something agreed between humans (because computers don’t natively do meaning, that’s a human brain thing). No-one’s got time to agree that one of these virtually identical options means something different to the other :)

Surprisingly, they’re actually both valid as well, as of the current HTML spec, because `<a>`’s content model is defined as “[transparent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/content-models.html#transparent)”, i.e. the same as its parent.

See:

- http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/5341451

And:

- http://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pauldwaite.co.uk%2Ftest-pages%2F5341451%2F&showsource=yes

(That assumes that `<a>`’s parent can have an `<h1>` as its child)

However, it’s not valid under previous versions of HTML:

- http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pauldwaite.co.uk%2Ftest-pages%2F5341451&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML+4.01+Transitional&group=0

Answer (score 3):

From a semantic perspective: both (or neither).

(From a structural perspective, OTOH, before HTML 5 an anchor **cannot** contain a heading, and since browsers aren't all HTML 5 capable yet you should avoid the new form of the construct where possible)

If you are creating a link target, then `<h1 id="target_name">` is preferred to `<h1><a name="target_name">` anyway.

If you are creating a hyperlink, then having the most important heading on the page link somewhere else is somewhat dubious from a semantic point of view.

Comment: “since browsers aren't all HTML 5 capable yet you should avoid the new form of the construct where possible” — isn’t this one of those areas like the doctype where the HTML5 spec has codified existing browser behaviour, meaning you can happily use this construct wherever you want?

Comment: I've seen browsers breaking on block elements inside anchors. I haven't done an in depth check to see what circumstances this is under though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say `<h1><a>`, because `<h*>` are block elements and `<a>` is inline element, so it seems more natural to keep the inline element inside a <s>div</s> block, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

The header should be first in my opinion but I doubt that search engines would really mind what way round they are, inside the H1 just seems cleaner to me...

Answer (score 1):

Since h1 does not directly correspond to a viewable object they both are correct.