# FullPage.js links not working

Tags: hyperlink, fullpage.js

I'm using the FullPage.js plug in for a website. But I can't get the links to different sections of the page going. When you hover over the links it is displaying the actual links and it works if your right click + open in new tab, but will not go when directly clicking on it..

I've tried different combinations: 
    
`<a name=""></a>`
    
`<div id=""></div>`
    
`<div class ="section" data-anchor=""></div>`
    But also looked at different z-indexes..

This is how I've used the plug-in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                    css3: true,
                    navigation: true,
                    loopTop: false,
                    loopBottom: true,
                    slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
                    navigationPosition: 'right',
                    loopHorizontal: false,
                    anchors:['home', 'firstPage', 'secondPage']

            });
        });
    </script>
```

And for the body I have used the following structure:

```
<div id="fullpage"><div class="section" data-anchor="home"><a name="page1"></a><div id="footer">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#firstPage">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#secondPage">Page 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></div>
```

anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Please add the whole HTML markup. It looks a bit messy the one you posted and there's only one section there....

Comment: I have put the entire page on a webshost [here](http://www.catchbear.nl).

Comment: Nothing to do with fullPage.js. Probably because you are not creating the link properly. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023512/which-is-more-correct-h1a-a-h1-or-ah1-h1-a

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a bug in Chrome 44 and 45.
[I opened an issue on Chromium forum](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=525213)

You can reproduce the issue by trying the hover the link [in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f5pfoo83/7/).

```
var counter = 0;
f = function() {
    container.style.transform = 'translate(' + 50*(++counter%11) + 'px)';
    setTimeout(function () {
       f();
    }, 2500);
}

f();
```

[Here's the fullpage.js issue at github as well](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1471)