# How to add a h3 and p to an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to dynamically add a header element and two `<p>` tags inside an anchor tag.

Below is the code I want to achieve.

```
<a href="http://shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.com" class= "ui-list">
  <h3>Author: Shreerang Patwardhan</h3>
  <p><b>Description:</b> Spatial Unlimited is a Tech blog where, examples using Google Maps API v3 and Jquery Mobile are shared. I have tried to give back to the developer community as much as I can.</p>
  <p class="ui-li-aside">Last update: April 9, 2013</p>
</a>
```

and below is my javascript which I am trying to make this

```
var a =document.createElement("a");
var h3=document.createElement("h3");
var p=document.createElement("p");
var p1=document.createElement("p");
a.setAttribute('href', "#");
h3.setAttribute('value',"Author:"+name);
p.setAttribute('value',"Description"+finalsummary);
p1.setAttribute('value',"Last update:"+finaldate);
p1.setAttribute("class","ui-li-aside");
a.appendChild(p1);
a.appendChild(p);
a.appendChild(h3);
```

but the tags are not getting appended.

Comment: That probably works just fine, but you never append the anchor to anything `

Comment: have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023512/which-is-more-correct-h1a-a-h1-or-ah1-h1-a

Comment: Also P does not have value

Comment: Hi I am appending this a anchor tag to an li element and appending the li to an ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input fields have value, tags have textContent or to be compatible, innerHTML

```js
var name="Shreerang Patwardhan"
var finalsummary ="Spatial Unlimited is a Tech blog where, examples using Google Maps API v3 and Jquery Mobile are shared. I have tried to give back to the developer community as much as I can.";
var finaldate = new Date().toLocaleString();
var a =document.createElement("a");
var h3=document.createElement("h3");
var p=document.createElement("p");
var p1=document.createElement("p");
var li = document.createElement("li");
a.setAttribute('href', "#");
h3.innerHTML="Author: "+name;
p.innerHTML="Description: "+finalsummary;
p1.innerHTML="Last update:"+finaldate;
p1.setAttribute("class","ui-li-aside");
a.appendChild(p1);
a.appendChild(p);
a.appendChild(h3);
li.appendChild(a)
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(li);
```

```html
<ul id="content"></ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use jQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ui-list").append('<h3>Author: Shreerang Patwardhan</h3><p><b>Description:</b> Spatial Unlimited is a Tech blog where, examples using Google Maps API v3 and Jquery Mobile are shared.I have tried to give back to the developer community as much as I can.</p><p class="ui-li-aside">Last update: April 9, 2013</p>');
});
```