# Should I wrap a heading with a link or not?

Tags: html, anchor, html-heading

I realise that both wrapping a heading with a link, and putting a link inside the heading both work, but is there a convention or actual reason for doing one over the other.

So for example, is `<a href="#"><h1>A Header</h1></a>` acceptable, or should I always code `<h1><a href="#">Another Header</a></h1>`?

A question that everyone has thought of at some point, but was too afraid to ask!

Comment: Actually not everyone has been too scared to ask. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341451/what-should-come-first-in-html-an-anchor-or-a-header

Comment: OK, perhaps I should have said they have been afraid to ask since 2011!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of HTML 5, this is valid. Previously only inline elements could be contained within an anchor tag. The answer in this question gives some details

[What elements can be contained within a <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379392/what-elements-can-be-contained-within-a-a-tag)

Link to the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

So yes it is valid HTML, whether or not you should do it is up to you. Personally, I would have the link within the H1 tag, as it makes more sense to me to have a block element containing an inline element.