# Adding anchor '<a></a>' to my heading makes it dissapear

Tags: html, css

My original HTML Code looked something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
    <title> MDMX Music </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
</head>
</body>
<div class = "container">

    <h1> MY HEADING </h1>

    <p>Website text</p>
</div>
```

And I changed it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
    <title> MDMX Music </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
</head>
</body>
<div class = "container">

    <h1><a href = "index.html"> MY HEADING </a></h1>

    <p>Website text</p>
</div>
```

The CSS Looks like this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 600%;
    color: darkorange;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(../images/rough-texture.png);
}
```

Whereas before I was getting a nice big orange textured heading, now I am getting a tiny area with a few white dots instead.

I can't seem to figure out what could be causing this.

Comment: Your CSS rules are repeating, not that it is a huge problem for cascading styles, but please fix that and provide other CSS rules that affect anchors and etc.

Comment: @Sqnkov well spotted. Must have been a copy and pasting error. I have corrected this and still to no avail.

Comment: Put first your content inside the `<body>` not after the </body>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another specific rule for the anchor `a` inside `h1` anchor like :

```
h1 a{
    color: darkorange;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```css
h1{
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 200%;
    color: darkorange;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("http://ghostlypixels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vector-line-texture.png");
}

h1 a{
    color: darkorange;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
    <title> MDMX Music </title>
</head>
</body>
<div class = "container">

    <h1> MY HEADING </h1>

    <p>Website text</p>
</div>
And I changed it to

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
    <title> MDMX Music </title>
</head>
</body>
<div class = "container">

    <h1><a href = "index.html"> MY HEADING </a></h1>

    <p>Website text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out i had a rule for anchors in general. Color and text-decoration helped too!

Comment: note: There are *always* general CSS rules for `a` tags and its different states in the browsers default styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<a href = "index.html"><h1> MY HEADING</h1></a>
```

Comment: I tried that already, and after looking it up found out that this was a less correct way of doing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341451/what-should-come-first-in-html-an-anchor-or-a-header

Comment: @mdemont That is outdated. In HTML5, `a` is a block element.